# EaselJS / canvas change element focus during drag & drop

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, html5-canvas, dom-events, easeljs

This jsfiddle illustrates my problem best http://jsfiddle.net/sdg9/YYUrm/

```
circle.addEventListener("mousedown", function (evt) {
    if (evt.nativeEvent.button === 0) {
        square = new createjs.Shape();
        square.graphics.beginFill("blue").drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
        makeDraggable(square);
        stage.addChild(square);
        stage.update();
        //How do I give focus to drag blue square without having to click again?
    }
});
```

I have one object (red circle) that on mousedown adds another shape (blue square) to the canvas.
The blue square(s) can be dragged around the canvas.

I want to make it so on mousedown of the red circle a blue square is created and is immediately draggable provided I'm still in a mousedown state. Currently I have to manually perform a second mousedown on the blue square to drag it around.

I don't know if I need to give the blue square focus, programatically fire an event, or do something else to get this working. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is also listen to the "pressmove" event on the circle, but what you will drag is the square you just created :

```
circle.addEventListener("pressmove", function (evt) {
    if (evt.nativeEvent.button === 0) {
        evt.target.topObj.x = evt.stageX;
        evt.target.topObj.y = evt.stageY ;
        stage.update();    
    }
});
```

and the topObj object is saved on the "mousedown" event :

```
circle.addEventListener("mousedown", function (evt) {
    if (evt.nativeEvent.button === 0) {
        // Create your square 
        ...
        // Then save it as the square on top of the circle
        evt.target.topObj = square;
    }
});
```

Comment: That did it! It took me a second to realize what was happening but since evt.target is circle I'm just adding a topObj property to circle referencing the most recently created square.  Thanks.